# Retrieve Data from Firebase and display in seperate div

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a real strugle with that so any help would be really appreciated. I already succed to attach data from my javascript to firebase. Now i want to display a post like Title Content and Date in a Div which won`t override itself when i add a new post in my firebase, but to display it i na new Div.
Here is my attach code from my Javascrip to Firebase:

```
document.querySelector("#submitButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let postAuthor = document.querySelector("#postAuthor").value;
    let postTitle = document.querySelector("#postTitle").value;
    let postContent = document.querySelector("#postContent").value;
    let postDate = document.querySelector("#postDate").value;
  
    if (
      postAuthor === "" ||
      postTitle === "" ||
      postContent === "" ||
      postDate === ""
    ) {
      alert("Fields Empty");
    } else {
      db.collection("posts")
        .doc()
        .set({
          author: postAuthor,
          createdAt: postDate,
          postName: postTitle,
          postContent: postContent
        });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
db.collection("posts")
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      let elm = document.createElement("div");
      elm.innerText = doc.data().postContent;
      document.body.appendChild(elm);
    });
  });
```

There's probably many things that you'd want to change and improve about this, so I recommend reading/following some tutorials about generating HTML dynamically, and this [introductory Firestore codelab for web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-web#0).